# Code optimization for the code to read the excel file in java

Tags: java, excel, optimization

The following code snippet reads the data from the workbook(Excel) and stores it as list of row objects.

```
for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
    for (Row row : sheet){
        if (row.getRowNum() > 0)
            fblist.add(readRow(row));
    }   
}
```

`readRow()` method returns an object which is added to the list. How do I optimize the code, like every iteration the condition `if (row.getRowNum() > 0)` is being checked. Is there any way that I can start adding the object into the list from the 1st row directly so that that `if (row.getRowNum() > 0)` condition is not checked every time?

Comment: I suggest posting it on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. Post a minimal example of the usage, your algorithms and state on how you want the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

An Optimization according to this [link.](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)

```
for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
int rowStart = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
int rowEnd = sheet.getLastRowNum();
for(int rowNum=rowStart;rowNum<rowEnd;rowNum++){
fblist.add(sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(0, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL));
}
}
```

In the above code there is no checking all the time..!